# change in options in select box on runtime while selecting options in a different select box

Tags: jquery, drupal-6, drupal-modules, cck

I have to implement 2 select boxes in drupal project first for a category and second for items related to category.
items list options should be change on change or selecting a option in category select box on runtime.
how can i do this reply if any one can help...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Taxonomy terms for this?  This isn't exactly what you were looking for but if so, you could use this fantastic module: http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select